# Installing KEGGscape

Tags: installation, cytoscape

Is anyone else having trouble installing KEGGscape (0.9.1) into Cytoscape 3.10.1? I uninstalled it because I was having problems enabling it in the App manager, and now it is giving me a "500 SERVER ERROR" code when I try to reinstall from https://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/keggscape#

Answer (score 0):

Yup, it's a bug.  I'll bring it up at tomorrow's Cytoscape team meeting.